# Where to Find Tomcat-Hosted WAR on Web

Tags: tomcat, configuration, war

Given a complete TOMCAT directory, how can I determine where my WAR will be hosted?

My WAR's been exploded, but I'm not sure what to type in the browser to access it.

Note that I'm ssh'd onto another machine, so I assume that forwarding's been enabled.

Here's some of my $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml:

```
<Server port="20310" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="60310" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" packetSize="65536"/>
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost"  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" appBase="webapps"/>
    </Engine>
  </Service>

  <Service name="App">
    <Connector port="45310" protocol="AJP/1.3" packetSize="65536"/>
    <Engine name="App" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost"  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" appBase="app"/>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should find it under `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/`, because this is where I put my webapp for running on Tomcat Server 6.0

Comment: But what do I type in Firefox to actually view the hosted app? Example: typically after hosting a TOMCAT WAR, I'll type http://localhost:8080 and view the app in my browswer

Comment: Whats the ip address of the machine where you have deployed it?

Comment: Again depends on a lot of things. If its within your lan, you can simply access it with its direct ip..but else, it depends on how its accessed by a DNS, if im not wrong.

Comment: you should type the ip address of the machine where it is deployed in thi format `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/your_webapp_name/`

Comment: Thanks. I have 2 exploded WARs in the directories specified by 'server.xml.' However, then I navigate to my TOMCAT site, I only see a Redhat welcome page. In my /var/www/html, I only have the sample index.html. Is there something I need to copy from my $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps to /var/www/html? Thanks Abu

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat hosts web applications and does not have a single DocumentRoot in the same way that Apache HTTPD does. Given the following location:

```
/path/to/tomcat/webapps
```

and a standard server.xml containing:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
  <Host name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" appBase="webapps"/>
</Engine>
```

then the default application (which uses the special name 'ROOT'), will be here:

```
/path/to/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
```

and will publish itself on:

```
http://<ip-address>:<connector-port>/
```

When there's another named application deployed:

```
/path/to/tomcat/webapps/myapp
```

it will be published here:

```
http://<ip-address>:<connector-port>/myapp
```

In your case you have configured two services, two connectors and two hosts, so you have two appBase locations, in turn you have two default applications:

```
/path/to/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
/path/to/tomcat/app/ROOT
```

and they are available on the AJP ports 60310 and 45310.

That's where we stop, because you haven't told us anything about the Apache HTTPD config and whether you've configured a reverse proxy to send traffic to Tomcat.

Why are you using Apache HTTPD?